# Is here has "CreatePipe" and "CreateProcessW" function in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, process, pipe

How to use the function of "CreatePipe" and "CreateProcessW" in Linux, when I compile the C++ code in Linux, there have some errors as follow: 'CreatePipe' was not declared in this scope. 'CreateProcessW' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: `CreateProcessW` would seem to be coming from Windows API? If so, that is not part of the language standard and you need to find (if any) a Linux or POSIX equivalent (in other words, you cannot expect C++ code that uses any of the Windows API to work on a different OS without some significant changes).

Comment: Those are Windows system calls. I think the closest POSIX/linux/etc. equivalent  to `CreatePipe()` would be `mkfifo()` if you want a named pipe and `pipe()` for an anonymous one (I can't remember which one the Windows function makes)

Comment: `popen` might be an option.

Comment: Trying to be cross-platform aside very simple console stuff between linux and windows has been proven futile. Pick an OS and work there.

Comment: There is nothing bad in using directly the API, because it can lead to optimized code. But it should be done in the lowest level of you application. And if you want to port it to a different system, you rewrite that low level layer with what is better on that new system. But trying to mimic the low level implemention of one system on a different one is er... *brave*.

Comment: [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) might be most nearly analogous to [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html).  [`CreatePipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createpipe) creates an anonymous pipe — the analogue in POSIX is [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).

Answer (score 0):

Posix/Linux:

```
int pipe(int pipefd[2]);
```

`pipefd[0]` refers to the read end of the pipe.
`pipefd[1]` refers to the write end of the pipe.

Linux specific:

```
int pipe2(int pipefd[2], int flags);
```

When it comes to `CreateProcess`, the Posix/Linux version is done in a few steps.

- Call `fork()` to create a new process - still running the same program - so two processes will now continue running the same program from the same point where `fork()` was called. Determining if it's the parent process or child process is done by checking the return value (the process id) from `fork()`.
- `dup` the file descriptors returned by `pipe` using `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);` to replace `stdin` and `stdout` for the new process.
- Execute a program in the new process using one of the `exec*` functions.

  ```
  // create pipes here

  if(pid_t pid = fork(); pid == -1) {
      // fork failed

  } else if(pid == 0) { // child process goes here (with a new process id)
      // dup2(...)
      // exec*()

  } else {              // parent process goes here
      // do parenting stuff
  }
  ```

---

Example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Pipe {
    Pipe() {
        if(pipe(io)) throw std::runtime_error("pipe failure");
    }
    ~Pipe() {
        close_rd();
        close_wr();
    }
    void close_rd() { closer(io[0]); }
    void close_wr() { closer(io[1]); }
    int rd() { return io[0]; }
    int wr() { return io[1]; }

private:
    void closer(int& fd) {
        if(fd != -1) {
            close(fd);
            fd = -1;
        }
    }
    int io[2];
};

int main() {
    Pipe parent_write, parent_read;

    if(pid_t pid = fork(); pid == -1) {
        // fork failed
        return 1;

    } else if(pid == 0) {   // child process goes here (with a new process id)
        // close file descriptors we don't need:
        parent_write.close_wr();
        parent_read.close_rd();

        // duplicate into the place where stdin/stdout was
        dup2(parent_write.rd(), fileno(stdin));
        dup2(parent_read.wr(), fileno(stdout));

        // execute a program
        execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", nullptr);
        // exec* functions never returns if successful, so if we get here, it failed:
        std::exit(1);

    } else {               // parent process goes here
        std::cout << "child process " << pid << " started\n";
    }

    // close file descriptors we don't need:
    parent_write.close_rd();
    parent_read.close_wr();

    // read data from child process using the file descriptor in parent_read.rd()
    char buf[1024];
    ssize_t rv;
    while((rv = read(parent_read.rd(), buf, 1024))) {
        write(fileno(stdout), buf, static_cast<size_t>(rv));
    }

    // use write(parent_write.wr(), ...) to write to the child.
}
```

Comment: ... or use `posix_spawn` as mentioned by Jonathan Leffler. :-)